# Django URLs working, but not clickable in a site template

Tags: python, django, pinax

Everything was going well until suddenly my navigation bar links weren't working.

If I mouse over the navbar, it does display the proper url, and I can even type that url in the address bar and it works. But when I click on the navigation bar link such as My Logged In Name, Profiles, Notices - nothing happens.

Actually it's not exactly true. When I click on Notices for example, my user menu pops up, neither of those links (Admin or Account) are clickable. All other links on the website other than the navigation bar seem to be working fine.

What would be causing this?

EDIT: Problem's gone, for now at least. I didn't even do anything. So bizarre.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate what's happening:
[image]

Comment: You should provide either a link or a snippet of source code in order to let people help you with this. If you are using Google Chrome, right-clicking on the trouble area and selecting "Inspect Element" can give you the source of the corresponding section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears, the error itself has really nothing to do with Django. It seems like you are using Twitter Bootstrap. (right?) If, as you are saying, the url appears on the status bar of the browser, you should check whether the link is bound to any event that should prevent the url from changing. In all cases, it'd be best for you to submit a snippet of your code altogether with the question. Without that, there's no way we can actually understand what's going on.

Comment: I can confirm that removing the Bootstrap.css removes all styling all together but URLs are still not clickable. Only those URLs that were in the navigation bar.
I'll see if I can post a code snippet without releasing any sensitive info.